# What does integrability of a strictly monotonic function imply about the tails of that function?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

In particular, if $f:\mathbb{R}_{+}\rightarrow[0,1]$ is a strictly monotonic decreasing function and $f$ is integrable then does it necessarily hold that $f^{-1}(1/t)=o(t)$?

Comment: If $f(x)\ge \delta /x$ for a sequence of arbitrarily large $x$, then $\int_a^{\infty} f\ge\delta/2$ for all $a>0$, which is a contradiction, so your claim follows.

Comment: Thank you!
(Sorry for the delayed reply, I only just noticed this received an answer)